# Single word to describe a person who works smart but not hard

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for a person that works smart to achieve the target, but without exerting much effort?

Previous answers to similar questions were in 2011 and 2012, and were just in the software field. This question is about a word for everyone.

Comment: You mention "previous answers" - which ones are those?

Comment: I've never come across a dictionary that claims to 'make up words'. I'd call such a book a 'bestiary'. // An adjective in the right area is 'focused'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Efficient" looks like a good fit.  An efficient worker gets the job done faster, and using fewer resources, than an inefficient worker.

"Skilled" or "expert" might help, too. A *skilled* or *expert* worker will do the job faster and better than an entry-level worker.

Answer (score 0):

Diligently? Considerately?

Those would be people I'd say work but don't hammer away for no reason.

Or if you mean people who are ace at their job not through hard work but by being naturally talented at it. Perhaps they succeed 'effortlessly.'